# Agora vs Bigbluebutton - Best solutions for Web RTC for conducting online classes?

Tags: webrtc

We are working on integrating a live video class room environment on our website. We have explored a couple of solutions - Bigbluebutton on the opensource end of the spectrum and Agora, Zoom towards the high price per minute end. We have started off the project with Bigbluebutton - but have some concerns - does Bigbluebutton scale well when we have 1000 concurrent users/sessions. Would appreciate if anyone can help us do a comparative analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need 1000 users in one meeting or 50 meetings with 20 users each?

"BigBlueButton is not a webinar platform", their product manager [wrote in 2017](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigbluebutton-users/sYYaXsaJWfs/8Helb3qkCQAJ) and recommended other platforms for such use cases.

The [load balancer](https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/scalelite) mentioned in the last answer in that thread is open source now, but I'm afraid if you want 1000 people to participate in one meeting, it won't help you, either.